# Why setTimeout() doesn't work and return value as expect when using inside useEffect()?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am making a countdown clock. In short, this clock will allow user to select the time and when the button start is click it will countdown. Click pause will stop the countdown, cancel will go back to select state, etc. The code is quite big so I put [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/countdown-clock-geubs)

The problem I have with this app is that the countdown doesn't stop immediately when I click 'pause'. It still countdown one more number before it stops (for example when pause at 5 it still countdown to 4 and stop at 4).

I tried to find the bug, and I guess the bug stays in the `components/time/index.js`. Below is the file

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Hour from "./Hour";
import Minute from "./Minute";
import Second from "./Second";
import { setTimeout } from "timers";

export default function Index({ runningMode, selectMode }) {
  const [time, setTime] = useState({
    hour: 0,
    minute: 0,
    second: 0
  });
  // GET value from the button
  const getTime = name => value =>
    setTime(oldValue => ({ ...oldValue, [name]: value }));
  // COUNTDOWN setting
  const tickDown = () => {
    setTime(({ hour, minute, second }) => ({
      hour: minute === 0 ? (second === 0 ? hour - 1 : hour) : hour,
      minute: second === 0 ? (minute === 0 ? 59 : minute - 1) : minute,
      second: second === 0 ? 59 : second - 1
    }));
  };
  // Bug might be start here
  // All console.log() below for the purpose of debug
  const countDownRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (runningMode && time.hour >= 0) {
      countDownRef.current = setTimeout(tickDown, 2000);
      console.log("runningMode true");
    }
    if (!runningMode || time.hour < 0) {
      clearTimeout(countDownRef.current);
      console.log("runningMode wrong");
    }
    console.log("inside useEffect() ");
    console.log(countDownRef.current);
    console.log(time.second);
  }, [runningMode, time]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Hour
        setHour={getTime("hour")}
        selectMode={selectMode}
        time={time.hour}
      />
      <Minute
        setMinute={getTime("minute")}
        selectMode={selectMode}
        time={time.minute}
      />
      <Second
        setSecond={getTime("second")}
        selectMode={selectMode}
        time={time.second}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This code behave strange in the `useEffect()` part, which I guess the root for bug. First thing strange is that the `setTimeout()` there return not an integer, but a lookalike object - which seem to wrong according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Return_value)
Another thing I tried is to change `setTimeout()` to `setInterval()`. `setInterval()` in this case return an integer - also oppose to the docs as it should share same pools as `setTimeout()`. Not to mention that using `setInterval()` make us unable to stop the countdown work - the buttons don't work

The second strange thing in this code is that the `clearTimeout()` doesn't work when be called first time and then work next time. I tried to track the progress of execution, and when pause is clicked, it did go through the `clearTimeout()` and didn't go through the `setTimeout()`, but the timeout didn't stop. I guess the timeoutID passed to it is changed when pause is click, but when I log that ID out it didn't change at all.

So I got stuck here. Guess it can be solve using *async/await*, but I want to  know why this approach above give out strange results. I also want to know how to fix these bugs to make the app work as expect. Thanks

Comment: I suggest make a single countdown and post it, your code is too long, minimize the problem.

Comment: @DennisVash Yes I did and this is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/setinterval-7begx) but this short version work while this one doesn't. That make me confused about what is the difference

Comment: Well, I would guess its something in your app logic, there are too many conditionals for a timer, I guess you missed something.

Comment: @DennisVash I think so but I guess this file has the bug. Many irregularities here. Like `setTimeout()` return not an integer but lookalike object. It doesn't right according to docs